# Rstudio Makro jump to code

Tags: rstudio

I want to adapt `Rstudios` implemented `Ctrl + Click makro` to my needs.

Current behavior:

```
source("subscripts/someFunction.R") # sources someFunction()
someFunction()

A_SUBD <- "subscripts"
source(file.path(A_SUBD, "someFunction.R")) # sources someFunction()
```

- Clicking (and holding "Ctrl" of course) on the string in the first line opens the script.
- Clicking on someFunction() opens the script also.
- Clicking on the last line shows an error that the file cannot be found.

**Note**: `Rstudio` cannot resolve the `file.path()`.

This behavior can be modified?

Kind Regards

Comment: Unfortunately, handling `file.path()` when Ctrl+Click-ing a filepath is still on the TODO list for the RStudio team -- you should see it work with full paths though, e.g. a plain `"path/to/file.R"`.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Could have been that there is some workaround, but so I will just wait :)